# Get linked Object values in Linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table line below.
**Table 1: Users**

UserId, Email,.....

**Table 2: UserProfile**

ProfileId, UserId,ProfileName,....

**FK** in Users.UserId --> UserProfile.UserId

When i get data like below..it's only retrieve User Object values only.I need to get the User Profile Objects values as well.

```
 var returnObj = _context.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
 var returnData = _entityMapper.Map<Users, UsersDTO>(returnObj);
```

Comment: LINQ-to-sql and entity-framework tags are probably mutually exclusive; they're both db access technologies but you probably aren't using both. Just because you're writing LINQ that makes EF do something doesn't mean you're using LINQ to sql, for example.. one of these tags should be removed. Entity framework can now refer to two different technologies with different feature sets. Please make yourself aware of which you're using and tag future questions with something implying EF core if it's core. Please also use a tag that indicates version number as features vary wildly between versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design the User and UserProfile classes as follows:

```
public class User
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

They are One-to-one related entities, so

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(_ => _.UserProfile)
            .WithOne(_ => _.User);
```

Finally, load your data:

```
  var result = _context.Users.Include( _ => _.UserProfile).Select( _ =>  new
        {
            Email = _.Email,
            ProfileName = _.UserProfile.ProfileName,
        }
         ).ToList();
```

this is based on EF Core

Answer (score 1):

If you're using EF Core have a read of [the documentation surrounding loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

If you're using EF 6 have a read of [the documentation surrounding loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

LINQ-to-SQL is really old now (it was dead 10 years ago) and a deprecated product. If you are indeed using it, Google for "LINQ to sql loading related data"